# Youtube title data is not selected.(in selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, youtube, title

[image: my code]
After scrolling down the page using selenium, I selected it as beautiful soup, but only 30 data comes in repeatedly. Is there a solution? Thankyou!

Comment: Please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't put images you can simply paste here your code!

Comment: Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)